# Combining multiple word document templates in to one document and displaying them in WPF page

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a reporting tool, which requires me to divide the main report into multiple sub-reports. Basically, recreating the crystal report designer with very limited functions and extra authorization option. I am storing the sub-reports into word templates, which I plan to combine and display them in one panel.

Currently I have telerik's radRichTextBox control added, but I am unable to get it to display more than one document. I am unable to figure out where to start, and if there is even a better way to display multiple documents. Any and every suggestion here will be helpful.

Comment: To fully answer your question would be too much for this website, but in short, you can use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` dlls that are included in the .NET Framework to manipulate Word documents. You can find plenty of online resources and tutorials to help you with this.

Comment: Is there any way to combine them together? Or should I use some other type of template file? Maybe HTML or just Flow Document?

Comment: Just open one, copy the content, open the other and insert the content. Of course, if styles and formatting are required, this will be more complicated.